# NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to retrieve images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am getting an error using a "properly working" code in another place:

```
[Error]: Caught "NSInvalidArgumentException" with reason "*** -[_NSPlaceholderData
initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument"
```

I declared an array of arrays `group:[[AnyObject]]`
In my `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my `UITableView` I am starting the following query based on an array which is an element of group => `group[indexPath.row]`.

I can get the necessary data without a problem, but when I try to use my `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock()` method, it throws the error above.

```
    var memberPhotoImages:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()

    let buttonImageQuery = PFUser.query()
    buttonImageQuery?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: group[indexPath.row])
    buttonImageQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
        print(error)
        } else {
            self.memberPhotosFiles.removeAll()
            if let results = results {
                for result in results {

                let buttonPicture = result["firstImage"] as! PFFile
                self.memberPhotosFiles.append(buttonPicture)

                buttonPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {

                            //...

                        } else {
                            if let data = imageData {

                                print("success!")

                            }}}}}}})

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this? tried a lot of typecasting so far, but it must be something else.

**edit: It prints "Success!", but also the error msg.**

Comment: **NEVER EVER** call asynchronous tasks in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Perform those in the `controller` part then update the `model` and then update the `view`. See the MVC pattern - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Okay I will remember this :). My issue is this: In my first query I am getting userIds of a particular group (classname:group). I am storing these into my group array of arrays. each array represents a group. Now my idea was to access these with within my cells with indexPath.row. Is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: The cell represents the `view` in the MVC pattern. Do it in the `controller` or in the `model`. Please read the short description about MVC on the site I've linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I had to guess from the error, it looks like you're trying to access a file that doesn't exist on the device -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument The issue could be that you're accessing something from a place where the simulator can get to it (possibly inside the iOS Simulator's files, which are in Application Support,) but the device cannot. Check your code for any hard-coded paths that might lead to a place on your computer rather than accessing the device's filesystem.

It show that your file argument is nil. Most of such cases are due to different file path between simulator and device. Check your code about loading file and compare the path between simulator and device.